# WCF Service monitoring directory

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to create WCF Service in c# in Visual Studio 2015 which will check automatically my directory with `FileSystemWatch` every hour or even all the time.

It is even possible to create service like this? Which will be call `void` function without request?
I didnt find nothing in google for few hours...

I dont have much experience with WCF Services...
Regards!

Comment: If you don't want to make any request, looks like you need a Windows Service, not a WCF Service. Is there any special reason why you need to implement a WCF in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. without request is impossible to do this.

You must have client that call the service.

Request can have void method but some WinService or ConsoleApp must call WCF service each time when You want to run WCF service.

Comment: Thank you! I will find another option.

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution seems to be a Windows Service or a console application running via a scheduler to check for file system changes.